# Dot Product, matrix multiplication etc

Tags: matrices

Found this in a book:
$$H=max\{0,X\cdot W^{(1)}+b^{(1)}\}$$
$$max\{0,\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0 \\0 &1\\ 1 &0\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} -0.4& 0.1 & 0.9 \\0.8 & -0.2 & -0.7\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix} 0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0.6 & -0.4 & -0.7 \\ 1.4&-0.6&-1.4\\0.2& -0.3&0.2\\1&-0.5& -0.5\end{bmatrix}\}$$

What kind of multiplication is this? It's definitely not matrix multiplication. It's not point wise ($\odot$) and I guess you can't call that scalar product. Bit confusing since such a multiplication has never been mentioned before in the book.

Comment: There are several negative entries in the result. Why wasn't the _max_ constraint triggered?

Comment: @greg not in the end result. I think you might have overlooked the curly bracke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that the term $b^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \end{bmatrix}$ is simply shorthand for:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7  \end{bmatrix}$$

and then you are left with regular matrix multiplication:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0 \\0 &1\\ 1 &0\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} -0.4& 0.1 & 0.9 \\0.8 & -0.2 & -0.7\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix} 0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7 \\0.6&-0.4& -0.7  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0.6 & -0.4 & -0.7 \\ 1.4&-0.6&-1.4\\0.2& -0.3&0.2\\1&-0.5& -0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: well yes i know. that's called broadcasting. but thats not the part im interested in. i wonder what kind of multiplication that is.

Comment: The initial part is standard [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) of a $4\times 2$ by a $2\times 3$ matrix, yielding a $4\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: ou... well, i see the problem now^^ so silly. thank you guys